# Hackerrank Winners chart SQL advance level question

Tags: sql

This is a new question Hackerrank has added for the advance level SQL certification. I was not able to solve it at all. Can anyone help?

> There were a number of contests where participants each made number of attempts. The attempt with the highest score is only one considered. Write a query to list the contestants ranked in the top 3 for each contest. If multiple contestants have the same score in each contest, they are at the same rank.
>
> Report event_id, rank 1 name(s), rank 2 name(s), rank 3 name(s). Order the contest by event_id. Name that share a rank should be ordered alphabetically and separated by a comma.
>
> Order the report by event_id

[image: Question image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? A little more details are needed for help to be provided.

Comment: @chegancasb To be honest, I tried solving the question but it is so confusing that I couldn't even start thinking around it. I don't have much of an idea about the ranks in sql

Comment: Please don't link to images - post all relevant information directly into your question, preferably as editable text. Also, doesn't the fact that you found it "so confusing that I couldn't even start thinking around it" suggest that you aren't ready to take this certification and need to gain more experience - rather than asking someone else to solve it for you?

Comment: @NickW I passed the test but couldn't solve this problem so needed suggestion on how to solve it. Sorry I will keep the thing in mind of not posting the images.

Comment: Take a look into DENSE_RANK().  Aside from a partiaion (which is the grouping), and ordering by (for ex: highest score first), the DENSE_RANK puts all those with the same score into the same position, so you may end up with a ranking of 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 per category being grouped.

Comment: @SchmitzIT this is the question which screenshot of the schema, thanks

Comment: @DRapp can you please suggest how to write the query please for a better understanding?Thank you

Comment: @DRapp thank you so much for the brief explanation. This really helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is some sample data for your scenario.  A table of contestants, and the attempts made. Made each person's attempts on their own line so you can see obvious different attempts per person.

```
create table contestants
(  id int identity(1,1) not null,
   personName nvarchar(10) )

insert into contestants ( personName )
    values ( 'Bill' ), ('Mary'), ('Jane' ), ('Mark')

create table attempts
( id int identity(1,1) not null,
  contestantid int not null,
  score int not null )

insert into attempts ( contestantid, score )
   values
     ( 1, 72 ), ( 1, 88 ), (1, 81 ),
     ( 2, 83 ), ( 2, 88 ), (2, 79), (2,86),
     ( 3, 94 ),
     ( 4, 79 ), (4, 87)
```

Now, the simple premise is each contestants best score which is a simple MAX() of the score per contestant.

```
select
        contestantid,
        max( score ) highestScore
    from
        attempts
    group by
        contestantid
```

The result of the above query is the BASIS of the final ranking.  So I have put that query as the FROM source.  So instead of a table, the from is the result of the above query which I have aliased "PreAgg" for the pre-aggregation per contestant.

```
select
        ContestantID,
        c.personName,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( order by HighestScore DESC ) as FinalRank
    from
        (select
                contestantid,
                max( score ) highestScore
            from
                attempts
            group by
                contestantid ) preAgg
            JOIN Contestants c
                on preAgg.contestantid = c.id
```

The join to the contestant is easy enough to pull the name, but now look at the DENSE_RANK() clause.  Since there is no grouping per score, such as say the Olympics where there is a specific sport, and each sport has highest ranks, we do not need the "PARTITION" clause.

The ORDER BY clause is what you want.  In this case, the HighestScore column from the pre-aggregation query and want that in DESCENDING order so the HIGHEST score is at the top and going down.  The "as" gives it the final column name.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER ( order by HighestScore DESC ) as FinalRank

Results
ContestantID   personName   FinalRank
3              Jane         1
1              Bill         2
2              Mary         2
4              Mark         3
```

Now, if you only wanted a limit such as the top 3 ranks and you actually had 20+ competitors, just wrap this up one more time where a where clase

```
select * from
(
select
        ContestantID,
        c.personName,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( order by HighestScore DESC ) as FinalRank
    from
        (select
                contestantid,
                max( score ) highestScore
            from
                attempts
            group by
                contestantid ) preAgg
            JOIN Contestants c
                on preAgg.contestantid = c.id ) dr
    where
        dr.FinalRank < 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- increase max length for group concat

WITH 
ranked_scores AS (
    SELECT 
        event_id,
        participant_name,
        score,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY event_id 
            ORDER BY score DESC
        ) as ranking
    FROM (
        SELECT event_id, participant_name, MAX(score) as score
        FROM scoretable
        GROUP BY event_id, participant_name
    ) t
)
SELECT
    event_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 1 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as first,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 2 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as second,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 3 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as third
FROM ranked_scores
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY event_id;
```

This is the correct answer and I got the advanced certification for this.

Answer (score 0):

[MY Reference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEBla.png)

MYSQL SOLUTION

using multiple common table expressions , dense_rank , Join and group_concat

```
WITH t1 AS
(SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY score DESC) AS 'rk' FROM Scoretable),

t2 AS
(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE rk<=3),

t3 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=1 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'first' FROM t2 WHERE rk=1 ),

t4 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=2 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'second' FROM t2 WHERE rk=2 ),

t5 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=3 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'third' FROM t2 WHERE rk=3 ),

t6 AS 
(SELECT t3.event_id , t3.first , t4.second , t5.third FROM t3 JOIN t4 ON t3.event_id = t4.event_id JOIN t5 ON t4.event_id=t5.event_id ORDER BY 1,2,3,4)

SELECT event_id , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT first) AS 'rank 1' , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT second) AS 'rank 2' , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT third) AS 'rank 3'
FROM t6 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  event_id,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY score DESC) as rank,
  STRING_AGG(name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) as names
FROM (
  SELECT 
    event_id,
    participant_id,
    MAX(score) as score
  FROM attempts
  GROUP BY event_id, participant_id
) as max_scores
JOIN participants ON max_scores.participant_id = participants.id
GROUP BY event_id, rank
HAVING rank <= 3
ORDER BY event_id, rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. fails the test case but did my job

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;


WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT event_id,participant_name,  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY score DESC) as rnk
    FROM scoretable
)
,CTE2 AS (
SELECT
event_id,participant_name,rnk,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id,participant_name ORDER BY [RNK]) AS row_num
FROM CTE 

)
select 
event_id, 
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN participant_name END, ',') AS first,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rnk = 2 THEN participant_name END, ',') AS second,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rnk = 3 THEN participant_name END, ',') AS third
 from cte2 
where row_num=1
 GROUP BY event_id 


go
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to this problem is

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- increase max length for group concat

WITH 
ranked_scores AS (
    SELECT 
        event_id,
        participant_name,
        score,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY event_id 
            ORDER BY score DESC
        ) as ranking
    FROM (
        SELECT event_id, participant_name, MAX(score) as score
        FROM scoretable
        GROUP BY event_id, participant_name
    ) t
)
SELECT
    event_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 1 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as first,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 2 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as second,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ranking = 3 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name) as third
FROM ranked_scores
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY event_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).